# Skeleton page with v-cloak: how to target loading div with css ? Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass

I'm using Webpack/Laravel and injecting vuejs on id `#app` in my page so to have skeleton loading page I want to have this markup

```
 //client side, will show after ~0.2 seconds
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <hello-world> 
</div

//server side, show for ~0.2 s then disappear
<div id="app__loading" v-cloak>
    <div class="skeleton">
       <span class="skeleton_ribs"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I managed to display loading gif in background as pseudo element when v-cloak and everything inside from `#app__loading` is removed, but if I add normal elements in markup they appear at the bottom of the page after `#app` loads

```
[v-cloak] > * { display:none }

[v-cloak] + #app__loading::before {
  content: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/65/ba/48/65ba488626025cff82f091336fbf94bb.gif');
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

But I would like something like this to work with markup inside `#app__loading`, but it doesn't work

```
[v-cloak] > * { display:none }
#app-loader{
  display: block;
}
[v-cloak] #app::finish-loading{
  [v-cloak] #app-loader{
    display: none!important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be expecting the content your initial element to be found in the template of app root element. When using `$mount()` function, Vue completely replaces the target element with the template of the mounted element.

This replacement is somewhat masked by the fact that, out of the box, the `index.html` contains a `<div id="app">` which gets replaced by the `<div id="app">...</div>` in your `App.vue` template.

But they're actually not related (and not the same element). If you changed the `id` of the one in `index.html` you'd need to change the target `el` in `main.(js|ts)`. And obviously, you could change the id of the one in `App.vue` as well.

Now, to solve your issue, you could simply place `v-cloak` on the div in your `App.vue`. From what you've shown so far, that should make it work as expected.

For more complex use cases (i.e: if you wanted to trigger a particular event bound to the initial element) the way to go would be to wrap the initial placeholder in a parent, bind to the parent and, later on, in Vue, target the parent with `this.$el.closest('.some-class')` or with `this.$el.parentElement()` to access the binding.

If you still can't get the expected result, please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you could use codesanbox.io) and describe in detail what is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To make your headache smaller till you find proper vue solution, you can grab loader by id and when Vue instance mounts - give display `none`

```
export default {
        mounted() {
            document.querySelector('#app__loading').style.display = 'none';
        },
}
```